# Can I make "Do Not Disturb" permanent?

Tags: macos, notifications, do-not-disturb

I've come to accept that there's no way to turn off Notification Center, but I'd at least like it to not disturb me.

You can schedule a Do Not Disturb time, but there doesn't seem to be any way to make it 24 hours a day.  If I make it 0:00 to 0:00, it's never on.  If I make it 0:00 to 23:59, it floods me with notifications at the tick of midnight.

Unfortunately, on the Mac, [Do Not Disturb turns off automatically at midnight](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph18740?locale=en_US).

Is there any way to permanently enable DND?

Comment: Even better, there is a way to disable notifications AND Notification Center. It's a workaround, but it should work theoretically. Go to system preferences, notifications, then choose each app individually. Under "reminders alert style" click none. Uncheck each of the boxes for that app. This way, no app will send you notifications so technically while Notification Center is active, there are no apps for it to display.

Comment: NoahL: That would be nice if it were true, but not every notification has a corresponding application listed in the System Preferences which can be disabled.  The App Store, for example, isn't listed there, so I still get "do you want to reboot right now?" nags.

Comment: I've got a third-party app that manages to send notifications without appearing in the Sys Prefs, too.

Answer (score 3):

I used the hacky workaround in this post on my slightly older Macs and it worked like a charm.

https://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/os-x-10.8-turning-off-notification-center-permanently

> **Turn OFF Notification Center Permanently**
>
> Here's the best way to permanently kill the Notification Center. Open the terminal and type:
>
> ```
> launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.notificationcenterui.plist
> ```
>
> The Notification Center icon will disappear from the Menu bar at the top. There will be a visible gap, but the system will close it up the next time you click the mouse. Notification Center has been terminated.

Comment: This isn't working on Mojave. Any leads would be helpful.